# what does crypt(3) and whatnot mean

Tags: linux, manpages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the parentheses and number after a Linux command or C function mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/297702/what-do-the-parentheses-and-number-after-a-linux-command-or-c-function-mean)

In Linux Manpages (http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt) I often see sth like this: crypt(3), bla(4), bla(5)

What is the full meaning of these expressions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The numbers signify what section the page belongs to, there are 8:

```
1 - General commands
2 - System calls
3 - C library functions
4 - Special files (usually devices, those found in /dev) and drivers
5 - File formats and conventions
6 - Games and screensavers
7 - Miscellanea
8  - System administration commands and daemons
```

for example, if you wanted to know how to use the `crontab` command, you could type man crontab. If you wanted to know the layout of the crontab file, you'd use `man 5 crontab`.

Not all items have all 8 pages. If the specific item is not a command, it will automatically direct you to the appropriate page as there was to entry in section 1 for the command. An example of this is `man strcpy` which will bring you to the C library function strcpy.

Comment: I didn't know there were 8 sections.  If I do a `man crypt -a`, I get a crypt(3) and a crypt(n).  Where's crypt(n) fit into those 8?

Comment: (n) is an unofficial section of the manpages added by Tcl. There is also (l) if you install SQL I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a "man man" to have the manual of the manual.
I'll show you the meaning of these sections.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the sections john describes is that the same word eg 'free' might be a user command or a C library function.

so "man free" or "man 1 free" would give you the page from section 1, if no number is given it gives you the lowest.

while "man 3 free" would give you the C library function to free memory.