# How to "See portage(5) for more info" ? The `man` command on Linux

Tags: linux, manpages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does crypt(3) and whatnot mean](https://superuser.com/questions/78493/what-does-crypt3-and-whatnot-mean)

`See portage(5) for more information.`

What does the (5) mean? How to see portage(5)?

BTW: Where should I look forward for such questions? This seems well known, but I couldn't find it in most linux document.

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/78493/what-does-crypt3-and-whatnot-mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section 5 of the man pages is for file formats and conventions. You can see portage(5) by executing `man 5 portage`. This will tell you how to properly structure a portage file.

You can see documentation for the man page sections in `man 7 man`.

Comment: man(7) gives details of the formatting macros (as section 7 is the miscellaneous section).  man(1) is the more direct version that includes the list of man page sections.  (this is on a Debian system; no guarantees for other systems.)

Comment: @~quack I don't see anything regarding the sections in man 1 man ( http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/man.1.php )

Comment: that's true.  that's also got a "last updated" date of September 1995 (`man(7)` on the same site is from 1999).  try this one (looks just like `man(1)` on my system): http://man.he.net/?topic=man&section=all .. some systems may list sections under `man-pages(7)` instead.  it will vary on the particular manpage collection being queried.

Answer (score 3):

Man pages are split up by sections.  This allows you to specifically look up an entry for `portage` in, say, **"File Formats and Conventions"** (*section 5*), by selecting the appropriate section from the `man` command line.

```
man [section] entry
man portage;          # pull up first occurrence of portage, any section.
man 5 portage;        # pull up occurrence of portage in section 5 only.
```

Run `man man` (or `man 1 man`) for the `man` manpage, which among other useful features should include a list of all the standard sections.