# What are the numbers in parentheses in the names of unix tools?

Tags: unix, manpages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does crypt(3) and whatnot mean](https://superuser.com/questions/78493/what-does-crypt3-and-whatnot-mean)

I'm talking about, e.g. in the git Manual pages, on the `git(1)` page,

> See gittutorial(7) to get started,

or

> git-add(1)
>
> Add file contents to the index.

Comment: @john: if http://superuser.com/questions/104060 is a duplicate of this, than this is a duplicate as well  of http://superuser.com/questions/78493

Comment: another duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/102229/how-to-see-portage5-for-more-info-the-man-command-on-linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are different sections of the man pages:

```
1  General commands
2  System calls
3  C library functions
4  Special files (usually devices, those found in /dev) and drivers
5  File formats and conventions
6  Games and screensavers
7  Miscellanea
8  System administration commands and daemons
```

git(1) would be explaining the usage of the command, gittutorial(7) would be miscellaneous information.

Comment: That's great, thanks. With the help of your answer, I discovered the Wikipedia section on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections

Comment: You're more than welcome :)